# How to shift entire row of a data frame by one position

Tags: r

I have a data frame and i want to shift entire row up by 1 position. The data frame is given below.

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
  5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2         setosa
  4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2         setosa
  4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2         setosa
  4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2         setosa
  5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2         setosa
  5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4         setosa
```

The updated version should be something like this.

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
   5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        setosa
   4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2        setosa
   4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2        setosa
   4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2        setosa
   5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2        setosa

   5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4        setosa
```

I have tried this:

```
a[j,] <- a[j-1,]
```

But does not seem to work. How to do it correctly.

Edited: it looks something like this

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
       5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        setosa
       4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2        setosa
       4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2        setosa
       4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2        setosa
       5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2        setosa
       AAA         bbb          ccc         ddd        dem   ##### new row 
       5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4        setosa
```

Comment: just to mention that you need to feed the line you insert with values, if no values, NA would be considered. You can't insert a "blank line"  as such. Or maybe would want to split your initial data.frame in two data.frames starting an index.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel i think its not working. i need to place other row on the empty place.

Comment: @Hashimkhan Can you provide more details?  Making a row as empty `''` will convert the column from numeric to `character` class.   It is always safe to have `NA` values in those rows.

Comment: as such, the question is answered because .. you did not mention which row to insert :)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel..If i want to use that empty column for other row... can i do that. i don't want to be `NA`

Comment: @Hashimkhan I already gave you the reason why you shouldn't change it to `''`.  If you still want to persist on those, you can.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I bet it is wrong. I can't see any value in adding a "blank" row to a data.frame. You should explain what is your real issue and why you think to add that row. There are very likely much better ways to solve your issue (whichever it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table` (Assuming that you have 6 "row" dataset)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[,.I[1:(.N+1)] ,by=(seq_len(nrow(df))-1)%/%5+1]$V1][!.N]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6:           NA          NA           NA          NA      NA
#7:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

#### Update

Using `base R` (Assuming that there are no "factor" columns)

```
indx <- nrow(df) 
df[c(1:(indx - 1),(indx + 1):indx), ] #credit to @David Arenburg
df1[indx,] <- c('AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'dem')
row.names(df1) <- NULL
df1
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5             5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          AAA         bbb          ccc         ddd     dem
#7           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

NOTE: The above step should convert all the columns from "numeric" to "character"

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, but I think you can avoid the `rbind`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, the OP is changing the expected result, so I don't know what he really wanted.

Comment: @DAvidArenburg, Thanks, that was my intention, but I was too lazy to generalize :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data <- iris
data$Species <- as.character(data$Species)
df = data
up_row_num = 3
up_row_val = c("AAA","bbb","ccc","ddd","dem" )
head(data.frame(rbind(df[1:up_row,],up_row_val , df[(up_row+1):nrow(df),]),
                row.names =1:(nrow(df)+1)))

 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          AAA         bbb          ccc         ddd     dem
5          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
6            5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: This is almost the same as 
Colonel Beauvel's method except that you used `''` and instead of changing the 5th row to `''`, it is the 4th row.

Comment: But it is more relevant to the requirement and row names is also added

Comment: I did find that, but ColonelBeauvel also updated before you.  So, your solution is just changing the `row.names` which is very easy to do.

Comment: In the mean time I was updating mine answer. I am thinking it is the simpler one and easy to update.

Comment: I do not know what is the purpose to copy/paste code rather than finding alternative solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
df = head(iris)
index = 5
newDF = rbind(df[1:index,], NA, df[(index+1):nrow(df),])

#>newDF
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
#61          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

According to your edit, you would proceed like:

```
df$Species=as.character(df$Species)
newDF = rbind(df[1:index,], c('AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'dem'), df[(index+1):nrow(df),])
```

But this is NOT a good way to do since you mix in the fourth first column numerics values and characters, transforming implicitely the numerics values to characters.

Comment: As I said it is safer to insert NA's. Can you explain "If i want to use that empty column for other row." ? For which use?
Or you meant "if I want to use that empty row for other column"?
In the last case there's no problem having NA. You can then do df[index+1,1] = 5.1 for example.

Comment: I mean, i want to use that empty row for other row. its show above in the edited version.